# Mysql str_to_date shows null instead of formatted date

Tags: mysql, sql, str-to-date

I am facing a silly problem while converting datetime column into y-m-d format.

I am running following query :

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(dateadded, '%y-%m-%d') FROM my_table
```

Note : The dateadded column is a type of datetime.

Whenever I am running above query it always shows (NULL).

Can somebody solve this issue as this is irritating me ?

Comment: Can you show sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your column is of datetime type rather than string type you should use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function as below:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateadded, '%y-%m-%d') 
FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will work for a four digit year in table

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(dateadded, '%Y-%m-%d') 
FROM my_table
```

while this will work for a two digit year

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(dateadded, '%y-%m-%d') 
FROM my_table
```

you can try this by following query

```
SELECT 
   STR_TO_DATE('99-12-12', '%y-%m-%dd'),
   STR_TO_DATE('1999-12-12', '%Y-%m-%dd')
```

both output will be

```
1999-12-12
```

[for further details](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)